# Is there a more efficient formula to use than just copying and pasting?

Tags: google-sheets

```
D3 =(B3^3.0)-(B2^3.0)
D4 =(B4^3.0)-(B3^3.0)
D5 =(B5^3.0)-(B4^3.0)
D6 =(B6^3.0)-(B5^3.0)
D7 =(B7^3.0)-(B6^3.0)
....
```

I rarely used Excel but since I don't have it installed on my computer I'm using Google Spreadsheets. Is there a way to formulate this so I don't have to keep on copying and pasting this formula?

Comment: can't you drag it down?

Comment: @Raystafarian Doesn't dragging down move not copy?

Comment: You have to drag the small square in bottom right corner or selected cell. Dragging from anywhere else will move the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B:B)=TRUE,"",B2:B^3 - B1:B^3))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[ARRAYFORMULA](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1FyJvp37QJcpzA-brSo3aBLqv_R0mO8Tgowbx69AnSYI/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the first one.
Click and drag the handle at the lower right corner of the highlight and it will fill the area.

Comment: +1 - also a good place to bring up cell reference anchors if you need the formula to remember a certain cell in the formula and not increment it along with everything else. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214143